# char array not changing when being manipulated in different function

Tags: c

I am currently working with files and sorting through them. So far i can open the file and read each line. Now I am trying to split up each line into specific parts. The only problem is in my function called convertLine() when i print line by printf("%s \n", line); it prints exactly what i want. BUT i need this to be printed in main and not in the function convertLine() that got called from main. Here is my convertLine() function:

```
void convertLine(char line[401], int *number, char fileLine[401])
{


    char firstNum[2] = { fileLine[6] };
    char secondNum[2] = { fileLine[7] };
    char thirdNum[2] = { fileLine[8] };
    char colonChar[2] = { fileLine[9] };
    char fullMark[7] = { "" };
    int length = 0;


    length = strlen(fileLine);
    ++length;
    line = (char*)malloc(length);

    strcpy(fullMark, firstNum);
    strcat(fullMark, secondNum);
    strcat(fullMark, thirdNum);
    *number = atoi(fullMark);

    if (strstr(secondNum, ":")) //this works
    {
        strcpy(line, &fileLine[7]);
    }
    else if (strstr(secondNum, ":"))
    {
        strcpy(line, &fileLine[8]);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(line, &fileLine[9]);
    }
    printf("%s \n", line); //i want to be able to do this in main
    length = strlen(line);
    ++length;
    line = (char *)realloc(line, length);




    free(line);


    return;

}
```

Comment: The code makes no sense. First of, C is call-by-value. Second, `line = (char *)realloc(line, length); free(line);` is completely nonsensical.

Comment: sure, i understand the confusion. I understand that C is call-by-value but then how come when i print the number variable from this function in main it has been manipulated? Also why would be reallocating space for my line array be nonsensical when the contents inside have been altered and may take up a different amount of space?

Comment: You really need to start with the absolute basics of `c`. I don't have the time to explain all of the errors in this program, nor do I really want to teach somebody who compares a string with a string literal with `==` how to write `c` without payment.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, i will continue to edit my question. the == was in fact a typo, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I think i may have a solution! I need to make the return type char pointer so that i can return a pointer to the modified array. This makes it possible to print the modified array back in main... I hope. Will give it a try now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `printf()` and `free()` from your function. `free()` and `realloc()` shouldn't be used in it as `line` may come from a non malloc'ed memory block. Call `convertLine()` from `main()` and after that, print the contents of `line` string. Then, you can realloc and/or free the string, if it was allocated using malloc/realloc.